# How to compile a C code in one directory in another directory using GCC?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I want to compile a C source code which I wrote in one directory in another directory. Is it possible like this? If it is possible how do I achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1814270/2072269

Answer (score 2):

Try this for compiling.

```
gcc file.c -o directory/myOutput
```

and run it.

```
./directory/myOutput
```

if this doesn't work try this for compile and move the output file to a directory.

```
gcc file.c -o [compiled ouput file] & mv [compiled ouput file] [your directory]
```